# Native SQL query with JPA Returns Whole Table not Filtering

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-ee-7

```
String name="abc";
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder("Select A_ID from AB  Where B_ID IN(Select ID FROM B Where ");
    sb.append(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)? "UPPER(B.NAME) LIKE '%"+name.toUpperCase()+ "%'":"");
    sb.append(")");
    List<Object> result= em.createNativeQuery(sb.toString()).getResultList();
```

The above Query is returning all the records of AB table not filtering based on **LIKE** condition
But

If I execute this query within the database it returns only 5 records,

very strange

Why Like is not filtering within JPA?

Comment: How is `name` set?

Comment: @TimMoore String name="abc"

Comment: What is log when pirnting sb.toString()?

Comment: Select A_ID from AB  Where B_ID IN(Select ID FROM B Where UPPER(B.NAME) LIKE '%abc%')  @Carmel

Comment: Is this block part of a bigger process involving transactions? When are the records inserted? All of them at the same time? From a separate tool? Please provide more details.